# JavaScript function $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i'm a beginner in JavaScript i have this code below that allows me to upload a file and send it to the Server to get back a response, that part works fine but the problem is that i after i get back the data i don't want to be redirected to the API link i want to make it so that i stay in the current page and get the data in the alert i'm not sure if there's anything wrong with my function but it keeps giving me this error in the console `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Any help would be much appreciated thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>

<form action=" API link " class="upload" id="file-upload" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>

<script>    

$(function() 
{
$('#file-upload').upload({
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data.xhr.response);
    }
});
});

</script>   
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add onclick event in button:
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit" onclick="uplaod(); return false">

Add this in Script File: 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>    
 function uplaod() 
{
$('#file-upload').upload({
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data.xhr.response);
    }
});
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to jQuery, after you define functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head></head>
<body>

<form action=" API link " class="upload" id="file-upload" method="post" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" name="submit">
</form>
```

NO IT IS NOT. :D Edited after the comment by @rncrtr -->
         
    
    $(function() 
    {
    $('#file-upload').upload({
        maxFiles: 1,
        acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data.xhr.response);
        }
    });
    });

Remember, browser always render the content in the order of **Left to Right, then Top to Bottom**. This means, by the time it tries to execute the jQuery snips you have written, it should know about `jQuery` of `$`. Otherwise, it will say that `$ is undefined`. This actually means that reference to your jQuery library file, should appear at the top of the document, that you are having jQuery snips in it.

**EDIT**: Moved the jQuery reference to the bottom after the suggestion by @rncrtr.

Comment: I would clarify by saying that you need to include jQuery FIRST before you try to use it. The function code needs to come after the jQuery script. Then it should work no problem. jQuery should be loaded in the footer for performance, but your code should load after it. You can put jQuery in the header, but it will be slower.

Comment: @RomeoSierra that helped but this new error popped up `$(...).upload is not a function`

Comment: @NigelChuan where is your `upload` function

Comment: There's no function named `upload()` in jQuery as far as I know.

Comment: @rncrtr Updated the answer. :) Thank you for that reminder...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are loading jquery library after the code snippet.Load it before any other code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>    
 $(function() 
{
$('#file-upload').upload({
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: ".pdf,.doc,.docx,.html", 
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data.xhr.response);
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load jQuery in head and add your script tag at the end of body tag

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

For reference https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp